# I'm having difficulty installing drivers for a Kodak Verite 55W Eco

Tags: drivers

The drivers download from the Kodak site and open when I click on the file but when I hit the install button, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

If you use USB connection, please ensure that printer is recognized and shown in output if `lsusb`.

According to OpenPrinting site this device [is not listed in support list](http://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/Kodak).

Official Kodak's site [lists two types of files](http://www.funaihelp.com/kodak/printer/downloads):

- *Linux 32/64 Bit* group has PostScript PPDs archive (*Postscript-v1.0.7.2-Files.tar.Z*), it has *Readme-Install.txt* with instruction.
- *Linux 64Bit* group have three deb-archives *Scanner Driver for Linux 64 Bit*, *Postscript Printer Description for Linux 64 Bit*, *Printer Driver for Linux 64 Bit*. I think you should install all them.

Also you may try to find your printer in the network and install it with `system-config-printer` utility (named *Printers*, contained in `system-config-printer-gnome`) and PPDs from first archive.